# How to do unit test console output with xUnit.net?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console, xunit.net

I have a method that prints private variable of the class.

```
public class Test
{
    private int number;

    public Test(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void PrintValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number: " + number);
    }
}
```

How can I create an unit test to make sure it prints value I expected on console?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make console output a dependency. Since `Console.WriteLine` will redirect its output to [`Console.Out` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx), all you need is `TextWriter` instance:

```
public Test(TextWriter outputWriter, int number)
{
    this.outputWriter = outputWriter;
    this.number = number;
}

public void PrintValue()
{
    outputWriter.WriteLine("Number: " + number);
}
```

In real application, you pass it `Console.Out` to print to system console. In test, you simply use fake writer (for example `StringWriter` based on `StringBuilder`):

```
const int NumberToPrint = 5;
var content = new StringBuilder();
var writer = new StringWriter(content);
var sut = new Test(writer, NumberToPrint);

sut.PrintNumber();

var actualOutput = content.ToString();
Assert.AreEqual(actualOutput, "Number: 5");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Console.SetOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=net-5.0) to redirect console output and do exactly what you want to do!

```
 var output = new StringWriter();
 Console.SetOut(output);

 do_something_that_writes_to_console();
 var outputString = output.ToString();
 //check for whatever you need here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the officially recommended method:

```cs
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

public class MyTestClass
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public MyTestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var temp = "my class!";
        output.WriteLine("This is output from {0}", temp);
    }
}
```

The result like this:
[image]

For more information, please refer to: https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output

Comment: This is useless if the output comes not from the test itself but from one of the classed being tested.

Comment: @C-F But this is also a way.Please respect other people's answers

Answer (score 1):

While the question may be a year old and is already answered, the solutions provided are not very good in my opinion because they force you to change the base class, or don't actually capture console output.
You can instead use this class.

```cs
public class TestWriter : TextWriter
{
    public ITestOutputHelper OutputWriter { get; }

    public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.ASCII;

    public TestWriter(ITestOutputHelper outputWriter)
    {
        OutputWriter = outputWriter;
    }
    StringBuilder cache = new();
    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        if(value == '\n')
        {
            OutputWriter.WriteLine(cache.ToString());
            cache.Clear();
        } else
        {
            cache.Append(value);
        }
    }
    public override void Flush()
    {
        if (cache.Length == 0) return;
        OutputWriter.WriteLine(cache.ToString());
        cache.Clear();
    }
}
```

Then, in the test constructor, you can simply do:

```cs
public Test(ITestOutputHelper outputWriter)
{
    Console.SetOut(new TestWriter(outputWriter));
}
```

And now you will actually capture console output.

Note that since `ITestOutputHelper` only exposes a `WriteLine` method, you may not recieve a few final characters if they are not followed by a newline. If you think this may occur, simply call the `Flush` method on the writer at the end of the test to print those few final characters.

Comment: Outstanding answer, very clean. This should be the accepted answer.